# Exchange - Access Mailbox Offline Mailbox Archive for User without PowerShell

Tags: office365, exchange-2010

I have been using Exchange 2010 for my family mail.  A few months ago, I moved everything to Office 365.

I moved most of the data over to the new installation, although apparently some of the old mail got left behind for a single user.

Normally, I know that I can export a .pst archive from my old exchange and import it into Office 365.  However, I have since deleted all of the Active Directory objects required by exchange, so when I try to startup the server I receive an error saying that Active Directory has not been configured properly.

Is there an easy manual way of getting the user's mail from the Exchange Server and moving it to Office 365 without the Exchange Service running?  I would like to avoid recreating the AD objects if possible.

Comment: If you deleted all the AD objects, are you sure you didn't also delete the mailboxes?  How do you  envision getting the data "manually"?  Have you located a copy of the archive's data on the server?  What have you attempted already, and what were the results?  Why are you specifically allergic to using Powershell?

Comment: I just deleted the common AD objects - not ones specifically tied to individuals (at least not on purpose).  I am not opposed to using PowerShell, but when I try to open Exchange Management Console, it says "No exchange servers are available in the Active Directory sites."  Would I be able to use PowerShell without EMC to export the data?  I haven't located the archive data on the server - where is it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this I needed to get the .EDB file on the Exchange Server (which is the file that stores exchange mailboxes) and convert it into multiple .PST files.

I did this using [EDB Mails](http://www.edbmails.com/) (Licenses costs $99 which was the cheapest I could find).  I was then able to use the Office 365 portal to upload each .pst file into one of the newly created user profiles.